# How to replace all the values put in an sql query in php

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP form a book this code is similar but it doesn't work
It unable to create required querystring in output

This the controller

```
try {
    include __DIR__ .'/../include/DatabaseConnection.php';
    include __DIR__ .'/../include/DatabaseFunctions.php';

    if(isset($_POST['quote_text'])){
        updateQuote($pdo, [
            'id' => $_POST['quote_id'],
            'quote_text' => $_POST['quote_text'],
            'quotemaster' => $_POST['quotemaster'],
            'user_id' => 1,
            'update_date'  => date('d-m-y'),
        ]);
        
        header('location: quotes.php');
    }else {
        $quote = getQuote($pdo,$_GET['id']);

        $title = 'Edit Quote';
        ob_start();

        include __DIR__ .'/../templates/editquote.html.php';

        $output = ob_get_clean();

    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
        $title = 'An Error has occurred';

        $output = 'Databse error: '.$e->getMessage().
        '<br>in '.$e->getFile(). ' : '.$e->getLine();

    
}

include __DIR__ .'/../templates/layout.html.php';
```

and this is the function

```
function updateQuote($pdo,$values) {
    
    $sql = 'UPDATE `quote` SET '; 
   $updateFields = [];

    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        $updateFields [] = ' ` '.$key.' ` = :'.$key;
    }
    

    $sql .= implode(', ',$updateFields);

    $sql .= ' WHERE `id` = :primarykey ';

    $values['primaryKey'] = $values['id'];
     
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   
    //  var_dump($stmt);
    //  die();
    $stmt->execute($value);
    }
```

output of var_dump is

```
object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(180) "UPDATE `quote` SET ` id ` = :id, ` quote_text ` = :quote_text, ` quotemaster ` = :quotemaster, ` user_id ` = :user_id, ` update_date ` = :update_date WHERE `id` = :primarykey " }
```

Is there a way to replace all :key with value in querystring
or is there another approach to it

Comment: You don't need to replace. PDO does. `$stmt->execute($values);`, but you need to put `$values` in, not `$value`.

Comment: You put too many spaces here `' \` '.$key.' \` = :'.$key;`, it should be `'\`'.$key.'\` = :'.$key;`.

Comment: Thank you, too may spaces and name of index  `[primarykey]` was the problem also `$values`